# Drinking Water Treatment R&D: Mechanical or Civil Engineering Degree?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, water-resources, research

I will be a freshman in University next year. After graduating, I would like to get a job in the R&D sector of drinking water treatment technologies. I'm unsure if I should get a degree in ME or CE. ME seems to better prepare students for the development of new technologies, but CE deals a lot more with drinking water management.

Comment: Not chemical engineering ? Or computer engineering ? Or chemist ( don't make as much money). They design the process then hire a contractor with mechanical, civil and electric engineers  to build it. I can't imagine mechanical or civil knowing much about water processing. Maybe petroleum engineering , they process more water than any other engineer type, but not potable.

Comment: This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.